# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, between

how to fetch date by last ten days after execute the below query into   codeigniter

```
public function get_data() {
        $this->db->select('*');`enter code here`
        $this->db->select_sum('total_sale');

 $this->db->where('store_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()');
        $query = $this->db->get('one_month_report');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please tell me what is wrong  inside query

Comment: $this->db->where('store_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)');

Comment: thanks for reply but it don't return anything

Comment: database date format is may 05 2016 is it correct

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); after query..and run query in mysql directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is storing these values as a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, this should work.

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("-1 week"));

$end_date = date("Y-m-d 59:59:59");

$this->db->where("store_date >= '" . $start_date . "' AND store_date <= '" . $end_date . "'");
```

Comment: yes it works for me but don't want to show  59:59:59 this time

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select_sum('total_sale');
$this->db->where('store_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()');
$query = $this->db->get('one_month_report');
```

Comment: like May 05 2016- or - 05 05 2016

Comment: @user6171329: Its working with default DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

```
    $this->db->from('backbonedb'); 
    $this->db->where('status', $status);
    $this->db->where('date <=', date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->db->where('date >=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')));

    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```